How to use worker-dom@0.1.2 library for Clientside DOM manipulation in web worker?
I am currently try to optimize many-many html dom manipulation in frontend without using server due to small size of the server as well. I am interested to use this worker dom library tutorial to append Hello World heading as first trial.


import { upgrade } from 'https://unpkg.com/@ampproject/worker-dom@0.1.2/dist/worker.mjs';

upgrade(self).then(() => {
    function addHelloWorld() {
        const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
        h1.textContent = 'Hello World';
        document.body.appendChild(h1);
    }

    addHelloWorld();
});
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Worker DOM Example</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@ampproject/worker-dom@0.1.2/dist/index.mjs" type="module"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@ampproject/worker-dom@0.1.2/dist/index.js" nomodule defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="primes"></div>
    <script type="module">
        import { upgradeElement } from 'https://unpkg.com/@ampproject/worker-dom@0.1.2/dist/index.mjs';

        window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
            try {
                await upgradeElement(document.getElementById('primes'), './worker.js');
                console.log('Worker DOM initialized');
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error initializing Worker DOM:', error);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>



But why it still doesnt work? Previously I cant use same path just as the tutorial, now I cant see the Hello World heading in the webpage. Thank you for your attention.
Ref: https://www.jameslmilner.com/posts/worker-dom/

worker-dom is an abandoned project.  Don't bother using it.
